# Contact pictures take too long to load

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to make an app for windows phone which requires to show a list of contacts as shown in the people hub.

This is the xaml for displaying a contact.

```
<toolkit:LongListMultiSelector x:Name="ContactList" IsGroupingEnabled="True" HideEmptyGroups="True">
    <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Border BorderThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" >
                    <Image Source=" {Binding Converter={StaticResource ContactPictureConverter}}" Width="48" Height="48" Stretch="Fill" />
                </Border>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:LongListMultiSelector>
```

This is the ContactPicureConverter

```
public class ContactPictureConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Contact c = value as Contact;
        if (c == null) return null;

        System.IO.Stream imageStream = c.GetPicture();
        if (null != imageStream)
        {
            return Microsoft.Phone.PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(imageStream);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Also I assign the contacts in the constructor as follow

```
    public ContactListPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Contacts cons = new Contacts();
        cons.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>((sender,e)=>{ContactList.DataContext=e.Results;});
        cons.SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.None, "bla");
    }
```

But when I open this page, the contacts take too long to load. However when I open the same list of contacts in the people hub, it loads much faster.
So what can I do to make the contacts load instantly.

Answer (score 0):

You could preload the images and save them as a BitmapImage. So you don't have to reload the images everytime you open the page. And I think there should be a way to laod them async.

Just make a new class and bind the list of the new class to your LongListMultiSelector

new class:

prop contact,
prop BitmapImage